# Replace in file with Huge String (Argument list too long)

Tags: linux, sed, string-manipulation

I have a file in which I want to replace a string with a huge string literal in the form "19209302","19209329" such 100 thousand of entries.

I am using sed and I get "Argument list to long" error, whereas if I use such 100 entries it works.

Here is the way I am trying to do in shell script
sed "s/@devices/$devices/" active_payload.json 
where file has a string @device which I am trying to replace with $devices a variable holds a huge string

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You can use for example awk (better GNU awk). But can you please provide example of source and target

Comment: with what Kind of Programm do you try to search/replace ? what is the file Format of the document?

Comment: You can save the sed script to a file and use `sed -f`.

Comment: @user286332 i have edited my question

Comment: Please take a look at the answer to the [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files) post. under 4. Multiple replace operations: replace with different strings. There you will also find a Suggestion to integrate your Patterns into sed files when they are large.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the string you want to insert into the stream into a temporary file first, and then use the temporary file as input to `sed` with the [`r` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html).

e.g.

```bash
echo $devices > tmp_file.txt
sed -i "s/@devices/r tmp_file.txt/" active_payload.json 
rm tmp_file.txt
```